# Unable to see storage devices on Resource Monitor

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, monitoring, windows-services, resource-monitor

I have a small problem after fixing some sync issues with my SSDs. It seems that I am unable to see storage devices on "Storage" on Resource Monitor's Disk tab.

I can only see the consolidated Disk use bandwidth at the right column, "Processes with Disk Activity" and "Disk Activity" though. Never encounter this problem on Task Manager too.

This is with Windows 8.1 (64-bits), and using the default view configuration on Resource Monitor.

I suspect that I may need to re-install some drivers or restart certain services.

(due to the lack of reputation, I am unable to post the image.)

storage controller:

---

Device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_8C02&SUBSYS_78511462&REV_04\3&11583659&0&FA was configured.
Driver Name: mshdc.inf
Class Guid: {4D36E96A-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Driver Date: 06/21/2006
Driver Version: 6.3.9600.16384
Driver Provider: Microsoft
Driver Section: msahci_Inst
Driver Rank: 0xFF2005
Matching Device Id: PCI\CC_010601

---

Thanks

Comment: What type of drive is it? And do you have any sort of utilities installed supplied by the drive manufacturer? For example Samsung Magician etc.. I've seen these change settings before in the OS which can cause similar problems.

Comment: I suspect that it could be a blotched Windows update, uninstalling and reinstalling Intel Storage drivers do not seem to work. So I did a system restore to a week prior, abit of a clutch. Thanks for responding.